# Start Facebook Livechat upon clicking a link instead of autoload?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

FB has launched Livechat API a few months ago. After adding the following coding  a small icon will pop up on the bottom right hand corner.

[image]

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.11'
    });
  };
  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-customerchat" page_id="PAGE_ID"></div>
```

That means, it will auto load when visitors visiting the website.

**My question is that is it possible to click on a link to open this live chat instead of autoload?**

```
<a href="#">Click here to start FB livechat!</a>   // something like this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the FB.init in a button click event. That way it won't init the chat element until you have clicked something else.

Plain javascript method:

```
<script>
  var narf = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.11'
    });
  };
  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-customerchat" page_id="PAGE_ID"></div>
<button onclick="narf();">Start Chat</button>
```

jQuery method:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $("#openchat").click(function(){
          FB.init({
              appId            : 'your-app-id',
              autoLogAppEvents : true,
              xfbml            : true,
              version          : 'v2.11'
          });
      });
  });
  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-customerchat" page_id="PAGE_ID"></div>
<button id="openchat">Start Chat</button>
```

Delayed [XFBML parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) method in standard javascript (as noted by CBroe):

```
<script>
  var narf = function() {
      FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('chat-wrapper'));
  };
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : false,
      version          : 'v2.11'
    });
  };
  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div id="chat-wrapper">
    <div class="fb-customerchat" page_id="PAGE_ID"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="narf();">Start Chat</button>
```

Comment: You can as well initialize it at the same time as before, but with `xfbml: false`, and then call `FB.XFBML.parse()` later on. Helpful if there might be other social plugins on the page at the same time, like button maybe - by passing a DOM element to `parse`, it can be made to look in a specific DOM-subtree only.